# How can i get First table records on base of third table by using laravel 5 eloquent model

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

Requested tables are listed below:

```
**User Table**
id, name
1, vehicle person name
2, renter person name

**Vehicle Table**
id, user_id, vehicle_name
1, 1, My car

**Booking Table**
id, renter_id, vehicle_id
1, 2, 1
```

**User Model**

```
public function renter() {
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class, 'renter_id');
}

public function vehicleBook() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Booking::class, Vehicle::class);
}
```

**Booking Model**

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'renter_id');
 }
```

**Vehicle Model**

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

**My Controller**

```
$renters = Auth::user()->renter()->get();
$owners = Auth::user()->vehicleBook()->get();

// In Loop
$renter->user->name; // renter person name
$owner->user->name; // vehicle person name
```

**Result**

On base of booking Table i want to get renter person and vehicle person name using Laravel 5 ORM.

I have done that using two calls but i want to know if there is any way to get result using one call ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. It will reduce the number of lines, but will increase the number of queries.

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->with('renters')->with('vehicleBooks')->first();
```

Comment: its not right because it shows all user records. We don't need all user records, we need only records that belong to booking table (renter and car owner)